# PostgreSQL истечение срока договора

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет, есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public.contracts
(
    "number" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT random_10dig_int(),
    text text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    conclusion_date date NOT NULL,
    completion_date date NOT NULL,
    supplier_code text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    store_code text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    archived boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT contract_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("number"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_store_code FOREIGN KEY (store_code)
        REFERENCES public.stores (code) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT fk_sup_code FOREIGN KEY (supplier_code)
        REFERENCES public.suppliers (code) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.contracts
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы в поле archived записать true, как только у договора истёк срок
Я пробовал через генерируемый столбец, но возникает ошибка о том, что выражение непостоянное, потому что там вызывается NOW(), как я понял. Я пытался сделать это таким образом: `CASE WHEN completion_date = NOW()::date THEN true ELSE false END`.

Через триггеры я тоже не уверен, что это решение проблемы...Нужно, чтоб это поле как бы на фоне даты менялось на true, и всё, как будто в цикле в потоке проверяется постоянно дата, и меняется поле, если срок истёк.

Comment: Вот ЗАЧЕМ? зачем извращаться и пытаться изменять значение поля, если оно совершенно элементарно считается в запросе? тупым `SELECT .. , completion_date <= CURRENT_DATE AS archived, ..`

Comment: Ты когда пробовал через генерируемый столбец, обратил внимание на параметр `STORED`? Это значит, что значение вычисляется не при чтении, а при записи, поэтому Постгрис хочет, чтобы выражение давало один и тот же результат при всех последующих чтениях. Очевидно, что использование в формуле `NOW` нарушает это требование. Так что сделай, как тебе советует @Akina